# WP Shopify Plugin CSS Button Color Issues

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a website, https://wordpress-625707-2032312.cloudwaysapps.com/, with the WP Shopify Plugin, and trying to change the default button colors. I have gone into dev tools and found the div class to change the button background. I can clearly see it's labeled as "wps-btn wps-btn-secondary wps-add-to-cart css-7k7g1c-buttonCSS-addToCartCSS-AddButton"

But when I use this class for my css changes, it doesn't work.  The change is "wps-btn wps-btn-secondary wps-add-to-cart css-7k7g1c-buttonCSS-addToCartCSS-AddButton {
background-color: #D71614 !important;
}"

Why is this not working?? I can't attach screenshots since I'm too new on here...sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are pretty lost here.
This is not actually a class:

```
wps-btn wps-btn-secondary wps-add-to-cart css-7k7g1c-buttonCSS-addToCartCSS-AddButton
```

There are 4 classes there, separated by spaces. The last one is actually unique for the first button. And in css, when you are styling a class, you should start with a dot, like: .class-name
The code you are looking for is:

```
 .wps-btn.wps-btn-secondary.wps-add-to-cart { 
      background: red;
 }
```

We concatenate 3 classes here with dots and NO spaces.
You should take a look at CSS Selectors:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thank you for that. I don't think I was that lost...but was thrown off by . the inside the div class as I have not seen that too often in my limited experience. But I was at least 75% of the way there :)